# Privacy approach in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

I have come up with an idea for adding privacy support in JavaScript. I haven't found something similar in the net, so I'm thinking it's probably because the idea is bad, but yet, I want to see some response, just to be sure.

```
var util = {
    s4: function() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                    .toString(16)
                    .substring(1);
    },

    guid: function() {
        return util.s4() + util.s4() + '-' + util.s4() + '-' + util.s4() + '-' +
                util.s4() + '-' + util.s4() + util.s4() + util.s4();
    }
};

// template
var Class = (function() {
    var privates = {};
    var getPrivates = function(obj) {
        return privates[ obj.getGUID() ];
    };

    function Class() {
        var guid = util.guid();
        privates[guid] = {};
        this.getGUID = function() {
            return guid;
        };
    };

    return Class;
})();

var MyClass = (function() {
    var privates = {};
    var getPrivates = function(obj) {
        return privates[ obj.getGUID() ];
    };

    function MyClass(a, b) {
        var guid = util.guid();
        privates[guid] = {};
        this.getGUID = function() {
            return guid;
        };

        var private = getPrivates(this);
        private.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    };

    return MyClass;
})();

var obj = new MyClass("private", "public");
console.log(obj.a, obj.b);
```

Comment: It's a silly example. A class with 2 construct parameters - a and b. a is private, b is public. The last line console.log(obj.a, obj.b); outputs "undefined", "public"

Comment: Interesting idea, but public / private support is generally solved using the [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript).  Does your approach offer a significant benefit to that?

Comment: This has been done and redone many times, see http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2013/05/private-properties-in-es6-and-es3-and.html

Comment: Chris, maybe I'm wrong, but the module pattern doesn't return a constructor, but an object literal?

Comment: The module pattern is the practice of returning functions (generally  members of *something*, the titular "module") that have scope-access to some variables that are inaccessible to the rest of the code.

Comment: It is very similar to the Java Script [Module Design Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).  You can read about it here and other similar Design Patterns and variations.  As people have pointed out.  Hmmm some one even posted the same link lol.  I should probably just delete the comment and say ditto.

Comment: you shoul look into MooTools class

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question,

as mentioned in the comments, privacy support can be (better) achieved with modules, or with IFFE's.

On the whole your design is not sound, [your GUID creation code is so weak in generating unique id's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Algorithm) that you will have overlapping GUID's and (hard to reproduce) bugs.

Furthermore, the variables are not exactly private if you can iterate over `privates` and see all the values stored in there..

Finally, I think you might have a pretty good case for a double assignment here, this

```
var MyClass = (function() {
    var privates = {};
    var getPrivates = function(obj) {
        return privates[ obj.getGUID() ];
    };

    function MyClass(a, b) {
        var guid = util.guid();
        privates[guid] = {};
        this.getGUID = function() {
            return guid;
        };

        var private = getPrivates(this);
        private.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    };

    return MyClass;
})();
```

could be

```
var MyClass = (function() {
    var privates = {};

    function MyClass(a, b) {
        var private = privates[util.guid()] = {};
        private.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    };

    return MyClass;
})();
```

From a lint/hint perspective you have some semicolon trouble, but nothing too bad.